# Accented filename from windows to linux mongorestore

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb, character, mongorestore

i'm trying to move a MongoDB database from a Windows environment to Linux Ubuntu 14.04.
Some collections are files named like "Vehículos.metadata.json.gz". Notice that the i has an accent.

When I type ls i see something like:

```
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 Marcos Marcos     103 jul 22 16:01 u_Veh?culos.metadata.json.gz
```

The problem is that when i try to run mongorestore it crahses on those files.

```
Failed: RTV.Veh▒culos: error creating collection RTV.Veh▒culos: error running create command: 22: Invalid argument
```

I already changed locale to "es_AR.utf8"
I don't know if it's a problem with Linux, the original file or the mongorestore.

Any ideas?